# Spring OAuth2 "Full authentication is required to access this resource error" when trying to access login url

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Security OAuth2 (Spring Boot 2.0.2 + Spring Cloud Finchley) and trying to initiate an implicit login. The browser redirects me to the /login URL but I get the the error "Full authentication is required to access this resource." How do I allow the login page to be displayed but still allow all REST urls to be secured?

My config is as follows:

App.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

OAuth2Config.java

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("XXXXX")
                .secret("XXXXX")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password", "client_credentials")
                .scopes("webclient", "mobileclient");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
      endpoints
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurer.java

```
@Configuration
@Order(-20) // EDIT
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

   @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()  
                .withUser("XXXXX"). password("XXXXXX").roles("USER");
    }

    // EDIT

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().permitAll()
        .and().httpBasic().and()
        .requestMatchers()
        //specify urls handled
        .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
        .antMatchers("/fonts/**", "/js/**", "/css/**")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/fonts/**", "/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Addd Spring Security log with `DEBUG` level. It will show the reason.

Comment: I think the error was due to all requests requiring authentication. I found that adding the @Order(-20) annotation and adding the configure http security method (see edits above) to the WebSecurityConfigurer class displays the login page. Just wanted to check this is the correct way to do this?